Different view-transitions depending on navigation
I am building an angular app with multiple pages. Between the pages I have an animated navigation view-transition that slides in the next page from the right. Each page has a back buttons, and these animations should slide to the opposite direction, but I see no way in angular to specify what animation to use.
Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-opqbbp?file=src%2Fmain.ts
I looked at the guide here, it tells me to give a parameter to startViewTransition:
const t = document.startViewTransition({
  update: updateTheDOMSomehow,
  types: ['slide', direction],
});

but

startViewTransition does not take any arguments of that kind, and
I don't have access to startViewTransition from within angular.

I expect angular to allow me to set the view transition name somewhere, e.g. in the withViewTransitions setting of the router, but I can't find it.

I found some interesting tidbits: the example in the guide linked above seems to work, but it's not the official api, so maybe it only works in chrome.
Here is the w3 specification of startViewTransition
and in angular there is no way to set the parameters, as can be seen in the angular withViewTransition implementation.

You can do it in the "old style"
Imagine you have an animation like
export const slideInAnimation =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition(':increment', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ], { optional: true }),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('200ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }))
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
        ], { optional: true }),
      ]),
    ]),
    transition(':decrement', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ], { optional: true }),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('200ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }))
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' }))
        ], { optional: true }),
      ]),
    ])
  ]);

We can to have a main.ts like, e.g.
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/page-2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/page-3">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div [@routeAnimations]="direction">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

Just only need change the variable "direction" increment or decrement his value.
We can use a series of "if", but we are going to think in a better way.
Imagine your routes defined like
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Page1,
    data: { order: 0 },
  },
  {
    path: 'page-2',
    component: Page2,
    data: { order: 1 },
  },
  {
    path: 'page-3',
    component: Page3,
    data: { order: 2 },
  },
];

See that in "data" I choose add an object with "order" propertie. Then only need when navigationEnd change the variable. So, in ngOnInit of the app we can do
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(
          (event: any) =>
            (routes.find((x) => event.url == '/' + x.path)?.data || {
              order: -1,
            })['order']
        ),
        pairwise()
      )
      .subscribe((res: number[]) => (this.direction += res[0] - res[1]));
  }

A stackblitz
